# How to list and delete files faster in Databricks - using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I want to implement efficient file listing and deletion on Databricks using pyspark. The following link has an implementation in Scala, is there an equivalent pyspark version?

https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/data/list-delete-files-faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbutils`, the DataBricks file utility APIs.

To delete a file or a directory:

```py
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/filepath")
```

To delete all files from a dir, and optionally delete the dir, I use a custom written util function:

```py
def empty_dir(dir_path, remove_dir=False):
  listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(dir_path)
  for _file in listFiles:
    if _file.isFile():
      dbutils.fs.rm(_file.path)
  if remove_dir:
    dbutils.fs.rm(dir_path)
```

Comment: Hi - this implementation is too slow for large trees